# How to split string by space with exceptions

Tags: java, regex, parsing, text-parsing, string-parsing

I am building Java voice controlled calculator and I have problem with parsing input. For example I have input

> ten divide by five

and I want to split this string by spaces into an array, but I want "divide by" not to be split so the output should look like

- ten
- divide by
- five

Please help. I tried to use regular expressions but with no luck.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You may define a list of non-split phrases (e.g. `divide by`, `equals to`) and instead of splitting by space match all such phrases or single words using alternation:

```
\b(?:divide by|equals to)\b|\w+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QhNvGo/1

And the Java code:

```
String input = "ten divide by five equals to two";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:divide by|equals to)\\b|\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/X99lMK

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this, if you have a small dataset, and you know that the size of the following word - that should NOT be split by space - is always 2 letters or less, you could try regex similar to this:

```
\s(?=\w{2}\S)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bugQ4O/1/